# How to disable ERB debug output

Tags: ruby, logging, erb

I'm using ERB for a CLI application. How can I disable the debug output? Every time I run a command that uses ERB, I get debugging information on every time it finds a variable.

```
DEBUG: 2013-12-02 17:59:48 -0800: Looking for data source Users/tjbiddle/Projects/gh/packaging/puppet/hieradata/beta
DEBUG: 2013-12-02 17:59:48 -0800: Found debug in Users/tjbiddle/Projects/gh/packaging/puppet/hieradata/beta
DEBUG: 2013-12-02 17:59:48 -0800: Looking up stateConnectionString in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2013-12-02 17:59:48 -0800: Looking for data source Users/tjbiddle/Projects/gh/packaging/puppet/hieradata/beta
DEBUG: 2013-12-02 17:59:48 -0800: Found stateConnectionString in Users/tjbiddle/Projects/gh/packaging/puppet/hieradata/beta
```

Edit:

The templating works - it's simply the logging that isn't, here's how I am instantiating the ERB object below.

```
    # Load the template into ERB.
    web_config = ERB.new(web_config_content)

    # Print the templated file.
    hb = HieraBinding.new(handler.project_root, environment)
    File.open(destination, 'w+') { |file| file.write(web_config.result(hb.get_binding)) }
```

Comment: I don't think ERB logs anything. Are you sure the DEBUG messages are not coming from somewhere else? It might be caused by the code in `web_config_content`.

Comment: @mechanicalfish - That's what I get for working on little sleep. Can't believe I missed that, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mechanicalfish suggested, something other than ERB is logging the DEBUG statements.

Specifically, it appears that the [hiera](https://github.com/puppetlabs/hiera/blob/master/lib/hiera/console_logger.rb#L9) gem is the source of these statements.

You should be able to override this logging by plugging in the [NO-OP Logger](https://github.com/puppetlabs/hiera/blob/master/lib/hiera/noop_logger.rb).  Check out the [sample configuration](https://github.com/puppetlabs/hiera#configuration).

Comment: Ah - Thank you! Not sure why I thought that was ERB and not Hiera. Much appreciated!